# s3fs unable to mount bucket

Tags: java, ubuntu, s3fs

I apologize in advance for asking such a stupid question, but how do I mount a s3 bucket on my file system using s3fs?

I used the simple instructions given in:
https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/wiki/Fuse-Over-Amazon

I have it all installed and I put my credentials in the /etc/passwd-s3fs file and then I just mounted it like so:

s3fs myBucket /mnt/... -o use_cache=/tmp

But when I try to view the files (using the 'ls' command), and when I try to access them in a small java program I wrote, the directory is just empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Just to note: I'm running it on a linux server. I also tried it on a local Ubuntu guest hosted on vmware running on windows 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

s3fs uses its own metadata scheme that is not compatible with other s3 tools, so, e.g., if you're mounting a bucket using s3fs whose contents were created by another s3 tool, then the 'format' of the bucket contents (especially if there are folders) will most likely not be compatible

so, best way is to start with/mount an empty bucket and then populate the bucket with data using s3fs itself

Answer (score 0):

s3fs Reinstall

[s3fs-c](https://github.com/tongwang/s3fs-c) but "initial commit, 1.59 release"

[s3fs-cloudpack](https://github.com/memorycraft/s3fs-cloudpack) is commit ver. 1.61 ([install example](http://blog.cloudpack.jp/2011/10/aws-news-suz-lab-centos-ami-s3fs.html))